# Creating a program that simulates dice rolling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program in python that simulates dice rolling. I have not got much code but I do not know how to begin on creating the code for "previous_roll". This is made so that the previous roll is returned in the function so the next number that is generated is different than the one that was given before. This is the code I have so far.

```
import random

def roll_dice(previous_roll):
    return random.randint(start,end)

random_number = roll_dice(previous_roll)
print(random_number)
```

I know that this is incomplete, I just do not know what to do with the previous roll parameters.

Comment: That does not seem to make complete sense since it is possible to roll the same number twice when you roll dice. However, your main problem is generating random numbers in a way works effectively for your situation.

Comment: You don't want `previous_roll` at all.  It makes no sense, unless you want to simulate fake dice that don't behave like real dice.  With real dice, the previous roll has no effect on the next roll.

Answer (score 0):

Roll it twice, then check if its the same, if it is, then reroll it.

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    while dice1 == dice2:
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    return dice1, dice2
```

Comment: that would work however, I need to have the previous_roll parameter there..

Comment: This is a poor way to do it.  There is no need for a loop, even if you want to skip duplicate consecutive rolls (which makes no sense in the first place, unless this is some misguided assignment).

Comment: how would the loop go?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


def roll_dice(previous_roll: int, start_num: int, end_num: int) -> int:
    """random dice rolling excluding previous roll
    :parameter
        - previous_roll:
          number that was previously rolled
        - start_num:
          start of all possible numbers
        - end_num
          end of all possible numbers (needs to be n+1 if n should be possible)
    :return
        - new_choice
          result of the dice roll
    """
    # ndarray with all possible numbers that can be rolled
    all_choice = np.arange(start_num, end_num)
    # ndarray with all possible numbers except the previous_roll
    pos_choices = all_choice[all_choice != previous_roll]
    # new random chosen number
    new_choice = np.random.choice(pos_choices)
    return new_choice
```

This eliminates the need of a for/while loop which can become very inefficient.